# Give an example of Riemann Integrable function which has a primitive. Justify

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Give an example of Riemann Integrable function (discontinuous) which has a primitive. Justify

Please help me. I need an example of such a discontinuous function.

Is $f(x)=\cos{1/x}$ a right choice

Comment: A primitive of $f$ is a function $F$ where $F' = f$.

Comment: @RRL Yes. its true. Would you provide me an example of a discontinuous function like that

Comment: Please edit the question to be clear about what you are looking for.  Obviously $f(x) = 2x$ is Riemann integrable with a primitive $F(x) = x^2$.  Seems like you want something else.

Comment: @RRL Edited above

Comment: Your example $\cos(1/x)$ is almost correct. The function $f(x) =\cos(1/x),f(0)=0$ is discontinuous at $0$ and Riemann integrable in any closed interval and has a primitive $F$ given by $F(x) =\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,dt$ as we have $F'(x) =f(x) $ everywhere.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh What will be the primitive then

Comment: As mentioned in previous comment the primitive is the function $\int_{0}^{x}\cos(1/t)\,dt$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Understand, but how to integrate that?

Comment: There is no need to integrate that. We have a function $F$ which is primitive of $f$. That's all that matters.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: What would be the best way to show that $\int_0^x \cos(1/t) \mathrm{d}t$ is the primative? The fundamental theorem of calculus doesn't quite cover it.

Comment: @TheoBendit: If $F(x) =\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,dt$ where $f(x) =\cos(1/x),f(0)=0$ then by FTC $F'(x) =f(x) $ if $x\neq 0$. It requires some effort to show that $F'(0)=0=f(0)$ and happens via an indirect use of FTC. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1784625/72031

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 \sin(x^{-1}) & \text{if } x \neq 0 \\ 0 & \text{if }x = 0 \end{cases}.$$
Then
$$f'(x) = \begin{cases} 2x \sin(x^{-1}) - \cos(x^{-1}) & \text{if } x \neq 0 \\ 0 & \text{if }x = 0 \end{cases}.$$
(The derivative at $0$ follows from the derivative squeeze theorem, as $-x^2 \le f(x) \le x^2$.) Note that $f'$ is discontinuous at $0$, and has a primitive $f$.

All that remains is showing that $f'$ is Riemann Integrable. Note that we may express

$$f'(x) = \begin{cases} 2x \sin(x^{-1}) & \text{if } x \neq 0 \\ 0 & \text{if }x = 0 \end{cases} - \begin{cases} \cos(x^{-1}) & \text{if } x \neq 0 \\ 0 & \text{if }x = 0 \end{cases}.$$

The former terms is continuous by the squeeze theorem, and hence is integrable over any compact interval. The latter term can be proven Riemann Integrable by modifying my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2459659/248286).

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks. How to check the Riemann Integration counterpart

Comment: $f′(x)$ is R-integrable as it has only one point of discontinuity at $x=0$. Right?

Comment: That's certainly one way to look at it (it's also important to note that $f'$ is bounded, locally). I also linked to that answer because it almost directly deals with $\cos(x^{-1})$. The only difference is that it's compressed by a factor of $\pi$, and potentially you want a symmetric interval like $[-1, 1]$, instead of something like $[0, 1]$.

Comment: Thanks. So the conclusion is "Discontinuities in $f(x)$ can allow the existence of its Primitive $F(x)$". But it contradints with "no discontinuous function has a primitive"

Comment: Yes. Mine and RRL's answer contradict each other.

Comment: Please see: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=7I-RCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA122&lpg=PA122&dq=discontinuous+function+that+has+a+primitive,&source=bl&ots=0UI7XLml-S&sig=o-4lJKzu-tQLnfT1jawDrmOreMI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr_7ekiNTZAhVKp48KHTOEC1cQ6AEIdjAI#v=onepage&q=presence%20of%20jump&f=false

Comment: It says that presence of jump discontinuity in f(x) prevents the existance of primitive

Comment: That's true. A jump discontinuity in a derivative will violate Darboux's theorem, which RRL refers to. If you take a small enough interval around the jump discontinuity, the function to the left will be close enough to the left limit, and similarly to the right as well, that there will be a gap, locally, in the range of the function. This violates the intermediate value property. However, not every discontinuity is a jump discontinuity!

Comment: @TheoBendit: I think you are correct.  Nice answer.